# mac osx rvm install ruby failed

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I'm trying to install ruby-head after updated my rvm, but i got Error running 
'__rvm_make install'.

osx 10.12.6, rvm 1.29.3

Here is the install log

```
*** Following extensions are not compiled:
gdbm:
    Could not be configured. It will not be installed.
    Check ext/gdbm/mkmf.log for more details.
*** Fix the problems, then remove these directories and try again if you want.
making enc
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `enc'.
making trans
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `./enc/trans'.
making encs
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `encs'.
./miniruby -I./lib -I. -I.ext/common  ./tool/runruby.rb --extout=.ext  -- --disable-gems -r./x86_64-darwin16-fake ./tool/rbinstall.rb --make="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make" --dest-dir="" --extout=".ext" --mflags="" --make-flags="" --data-mode=0644 --prog-mode=0755 --installed-list .installed.list --mantype="doc"
installing binary commands:   /Users/Hao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Users/Hao/.rvm/src/ruby-head/libruby.2.5.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Users/Hao/.rvm/src/ruby-head/libruby.2.5.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

make: *** [do-install-nodoc] Abort trap: 6
++ return 2
```

I got no idea about this, could someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it just need to excute 'xcode-select --install' before install ruby